# Passing data from one component to another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have started to get my hand-on reactjs. I have three components which are placed in separate files. `mainPage.js` `list.js` and `tableDisplay.js`are the three different files. I have got few doubt after working with reactjs.

1. The output from `mainPage.js` is passed as inputs to the `list.js`, so here 
   `mainPage.js` is parent and `list.js` is the child(if wrong please correct 
   me).Likewise, `list.js` output is passed as input to the `tableDisplay.js`,my doubt here is, does `list.js` remain as child component or act as parent component for the `list.js`.
2. The output fetched in the `list.js` is a table from the DB. So Im trying to 
   display the same table in the `tableDisplay.js` page, for which Im storing the fetched data to be an object. But Im getting an error `Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {Name, Emp.no, Designation, WorkOff}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of tableDispay.` So what does this error mean and how to overcome this error ad display the table in the `tableDisplay.js`

list.js :

```
    class list extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            content: false,
            query : '' ,
        };
        this.clickEvent= this.clickEvent.bind(this);
    }

     onChange(e) {
        this.setState({ query : e.target.value });
    }

    clickEvent(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            content: true,
        });

         connectDataBase.query(this.state.query, (err, result) => {
           var dataFetched = result;
            this.setState({
                htmlTable: dataFetched,
            });
        })
    }

    render() {
            return (
                <div>                        
                    <div id="listClass">
                    <label> SQL </label>
                    <br />
                    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)} value={this.state.query}> Query </textarea>
                </div>
                <button onClick={this.clickEvent.bind(this)} > Run </button>
                <div id="third" >
                    {this.state.content && <TableDisplay tableData={this.state.htmlTable}/>} 
                </div>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

export default list;
```

tableDisplay.js:

```
    class tableDisplay extends React.Component{
     constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    }; 
  }
    render(){

        return(
            <div id="tableClass" >
                <label> Result </label>
                <br/>
                {this.props.tableData.map((x,y)=>
                <table key={y}>
                    {x}
                </table>
                )}
                {this.props.tableData};
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default tableDisplay;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think error is in this line:

```
{this.props.tableData};
```

**tableData is an array** (as you are using map on that), and we can't `render` any `array/object` directly inside `JSX`, remove that line it will work.

**Note**: You can convert the array to string by using `join` then you can print the data directly.

Use this:

`{this.props.tableData.join(' ')};`

I think there is a issue with table rendering also, inside table you are directly putting the `{x}`, but you need to use some `td/tr` to render data.

You need to define the `htmlTable` and `content` in state variable, initial value of `content` should be false and once you get the data update the `content` value to true.

Content of `tableData` is:

```
[{Name : 'Sam', Emp.No:'12809', Designation:'Engg.', WorkOff :'UK'}]
```

Use this to `render` table:

```
<table>
    {tableData.map((obj,y) => {
        return  <tr key={obj['Emp.No']}> 
                    {Object.keys(obj).map((x,y) => <td key={y}> {obj[x]} </td>)  
                </tr>
    })}
</table>
```

Comment: Im getting error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of undefined`. Also Im not able to see the table instead it prints `[object object]`in the screen..

Comment: {Name : 'Sam', Emp.No:'12809', Designation:'Engg.', WorkOff :'UK'} this is my content in the table.

Comment: this is not an array how you are using map on that ? you want to print these values in table? what are the headers name and where you defined those headers ?

Comment: don't update the content value in the beginning, set once you get the data: `this.setState({
                htmlTable: dataFetched,
                content: true
            });`

Comment: `Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {Name, Emp.no, Designation, WorkOff}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of tableDisplay`, the same error is repeated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144201/discussion-between-mayank-shukla-and-devanya).