# Rendering a table using reactjs

Tags: reactjs, amazon-dynamodb

Hi Im starting with the reactjs. After working with the basics in react, Im trying to work on the reactjs with dynamoDB. First query Im working on is `Select` query, and render the table in html file. So right now Im able to get the json array from desired table using `select` query. But Im not able display the rendered data in a table format i.e I get a json array like below and able to display data `4281, taniv, secondary...` but not able to display the header for each value (id, name, class, etc.), so how to display the header for each json value. I want it to be dynamic because I want to show what is in the db(if some of the attributes are not there or missing I don't want it to be displayed) :

[This an example I refered to get the data from db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43967441/passing-data-from-one-component-to-another-component)

```
 [
    {
      "id": 4281,
      "name": "taniv",
      "class": "secondary",
      "admission": 227,
      "telephone": "209-109-2322",
      "address": "11 first lane",
      "postCode": "5788009",
      "county": "UK",         
    }]
```

js

```
<div id="third" >
                    <label> Result </label>
                    <br />
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th>  </th>   
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                {data.map((obj, y) => {
                                    return Object.keys(obj).map((x, y) => <td> {obj[x]} </td>)
                                })}    
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <Paginator>
```

Comment: Can you post the actual React code that's not properly showing the header? We can't help you with this information.

Comment: @AndyRay I have include the js page where Im trying to display th table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/1wkYqLGno) on codesandbox.io for you (:

From what I understood you are trying to make your table completely dynamic. You essentially want keys in your object to be table headers and corresponding values to be table row data. Please checkout the example and let me know if this helps or if you have any questions you can find me on Twitter (@jonmajorc). Good luck!